# Pulling Properties from AD with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-ise

Im trying to pull just the names in specific AD fields, however I keep getting: "@{(Property)=Data}" when I write-host

'''

```
$TargetUserName = "User.test"
$Firstname = Get-ADUser -identity $TargetUserName -properties GivenName | Select-object GivenName
$Lastname = Get-ADUser -identity $TargetUserName -properties Surname | Select-object SurName
Write-Host $Firstname
Write-Host $Lastname
```

'''

**Result:**

@{GivenName=user}

@{SurName=Test}

I want it to just display the data within the result, so it needs to look like:

**Result Desired:**

user

Test

Im newer at Powershell, so bear with me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `write-host` to display values of a variable or object property. You can reference them directly:

```
$TargetUserName = "User.test"
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -identity $TargetUserName
$ADUser.GivenName
$ADUser.Surname
```

The `Get-ADUser` command automatically returns an ADUser object with a default list of properties. Surname and GivenName are included so there is no need to use the `-Properties` switch in this case. The ADUser object property values can be accessed by using the `objectname.property` or `(Object Expression).property`.

Comment: Ah I was over thinking it I guess - using your code listed and tweaking it a little bit for my usage beyond this is EXACTLY what I needed - youre the man (Woman, etc)!